# Understanding Random Forest probability

Tags: probability, random-forest

Lets say I trained a random forest on classes 0,1,2 as seen below.

Now I predict the classes probabilities with random forest for new points A and B.

Would I get...

For point A a probabilities classes of: 50% - class 0, 25% class 1, 25% class 2?

For point B a probabilities classes of: 90% - class 0, 5% class 1, 5% class 2?

In other words, does the class probability meaning is some kind of normalized distance between classes?

Now, let's say class 0 had only 1 point. Would this change the probabilities above?

Would appreciate if someone can put some light on this.

Thank!

[image]

Comment: Great question, although it's off topic for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. The short answer is that RF outputs might or might not be interpreted in a straightforward way as class probabilities. One aspect is that outputs are typically constant over input regions bounded by hyperplanes (i.e., lines in 2-d), so the output is not a smooth function of distance between clusters as you were suggesting. That's absolutely meaningful and useful, but it's not what RF do.

Comment: Another aspect is that some RF implementations output score = class proportion within region; that's an estimate of posterior class probability. However, other implementations output score = proportion of votes, counting votes over an ensemble of randomly generated RF models, and that's not a posterior class probability estimate. If I remember correctly, the most-widely used RF implementation in R (I forget the name of it) outputs vote proportions.